# Alternating integers provided in for-loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, pattern

The following code prints the labels *foo*, *bar*, *baz*, and *qux* on alternating sides of a circle. This is being done by for-looping over multiple variables specified in `\myInput`. The variable responsible for the vertical placement of these labels (i.e., their distance to the center [0,0]) is `varC`.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def \CircleIntervals {0,90,...,270}
\def \myInput {
    foo/45/2/red,
    bar/135/4/green,
    baz/225/2/blue,
    qux/315/4/brown}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect, line width=3pt]
    \draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
    \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in \CircleIntervals
    {
        \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:2.9cm) -- (\angle:3.1cm);
        \node[] at (\angle:3.5cm) {\xi};
    }
    \foreach \varA/\varB/\varC/\varD in \myInput {
        \node[color=\varD] at (\varB:\varC cm) {\Large{\varA}};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `varC` provides nothing but a repeating pattern, I do not want it to be part of `\myInput`, but instead hard-code it as part of the loop.

How do I modify the second loop such that the integers *2* and *4* are provided in continuously repeating order?

Answer (score 1):

A more or less 'basic' approach

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def \CircleIntervals {0,90,...,270}
\def \myInput {
  foo/45/red,
  bar/135/green,
  baz/225/blue,
  qux/315/brown}

\newif\ifdothis

\def\foostate{%
  2%
}

\newcommand{\togglefoostate}{%
  \ifdothis
  \gdef\foostate{2}
  \global\dothisfalse
  \else
  \gdef\foostate{4}
  \global\dothistrue
  \fi
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect, line width=3pt]
    \draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
    \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in \CircleIntervals
    {
        \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:2.9cm) -- (\angle:3.1cm);
        \node[] at (\angle:3.5cm) {\xi};
    }
    \foreach \varA/\varB/\varD in \myInput {%
      \node[color=\varD] at (\varB:\foostate cm) {\Large{\varA}};
      \togglefoostate%
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built functionality of `evaluate` along with `count` provided by Tikz. So we start a count from `0` and then we can do

```
evaluate=\xx as \mymod using {mod(\xx,2)},
```

where the results will be `0,1,0,1,0,1,0,...`. After this we can do

```
evaluate=\xx as \varC using int(2*(\mymod+1))
```

and the results will be

```
int(2*(0+1)) == 2
int(2*(1+1)) == 4
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def \CircleIntervals {0,90,...,270}
\def \myInput {
    foo/45/red,
    bar/135/green,
    baz/225/blue,
    qux/315/brown}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect, line width=3pt]
\draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];

\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in \CircleIntervals{
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:2.9cm) -- (\angle:3.1cm);
    \node[] at (\angle:3.5cm) {\xi};
}

\foreach \varA/\varB/\varD [
    count=\xx starting from 0,
    evaluate=\xx as \mymod using {mod(\xx,2)},
    evaluate=\xx as \varC using int(2*(\mymod+1))
    ] in \myInput {%
    \node[color=\varD] at (\varB:\varC cm) {\Large{\varA}};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a count also in the second loop and define `\yy` to be 2 if the count is odd and 4 if the count is even.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\CircleIntervals {0,90,180,270}
\newcommand\myInput {
    foo/45/red,
    bar/135/green,
    baz/225/blue,
    qux/315/brown% <--- or a space would be seen
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect, line width=3pt]
  \draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
  \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in \CircleIntervals
   {
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:2.9cm) -- (\angle:3.1cm);
    \node[] at (\angle:3.5cm) {\xi};
   }
  \foreach \varA/\varB/\varC [count=\y] in \myInput
   {
    \edef\yy{\ifodd\y\space 2\else 4\fi}
    \node[color=\varC] at (\varB:\yy cm) {\Large\varA};
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The strange `\space` is used to terminate the number for `\ifodd`.

[image]